# Failed to resolve "WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient)" reference from "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile, Version=1.3.0.0

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms app in Visual Studio 2017 and I am trying to deploy the .iOS project to my iPhone and I get this error:

> Failed to resolve "System.Void Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient::.ctor(System.String,System.String)" reference from "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile, Version=1.3.0.0

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: do you get that in Android project too? did you install your nuget packages to ALL projects?

Comment: @YuriS I don't get that error in android. I installed WindowsAzure.MobileServices to all three of my projects (the forms project, and ios and android)

Comment: Can you share the sample project?

Comment: This is a project for work , and I'm unable to share the source code. I'll try to see if I can make a sample project with the problem replicated and upload to GitHub if I can.

Comment: @YuriS can't seem to replicate this problem in a new project =(

Comment: See if you updated package to new azure package Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client. Update in cross platforms and in iOS project.

Comment: @Atul They are both updated to the latest version